# High Sierra partition on Macbook pro 2020

Tags: high-sierra, partition, big-sur

Is it in any way possible to create a partition running High Sierra on a macbook pro 2020 shipped with Big Sur?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to boot up holding down option key, and be able to choose between High Sierra and Big Sur.

Obviously Apple will not approve of this sort of unholy behavior, but I like to know if it can somehow be done.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

No Mac will boot to an OS older than itself, with the exception of models released right on the cusp of a new major OS version.

The drivers for the newer model didn't yet exist.

Your only alternative is to run it as a VM.